# fig.add_subplot(projection='3d') has TypeError

Tags: python, matplotlib

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcNUq.png)There is no problem with the csv file I used..

I tried :

fig.gca(111,projection='3d')  //but this gca() can't use in finalver

fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')

plt.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')

plt.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')

plt.axes(111,projection='3d')

but returned in every code was value is typeerror

This is my code...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import pandas as pd

data=pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\pks62\Desktop\지과수행\globular2.csv")

x = data['x']
y = data['y']
z = data['z']

print(data)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
# ax = fig.add_subplot(111,projection="3d")
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="3d")        //error(TypeError) for all csv files


ax.view_init(30,100)

##숫자

ax.scatter(x,y,z, marker='o', s=15,  c='darkgreen')

ax.scatter(0,0,0, marker ='o', s= 35, c = 'red')

plt.show()
```

have any idea...?

Comment: Please provide the full error traceback and the sample data, enough to create a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: but that is all of error message..